# Requests module requests same URL twice

Tags: python, mysql, web-scraping, python-requests

I am working on a scraper project in my free time and have run into an issue with the requests module.

I have stored, in a mysql database, the url details/parameters that need to be scraped by my program. I access this detail through a select query, and once returned, I pass it to the scraper via the build_page_load method.

```py
class Scraper:

    HEADERS = {
        "accept-language": "en-US,en;q=0.9",
        "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.110 Safari/537.36",
        "accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8",
        "accept-language": "en-US;en;q=0.9",
        "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
    }

    @staticmethod
    def build_page_load(url_details):
        page_load = np.array([Page(url_detail) for url_detail in url_details])
        return page_load
    
    @staticmethod
    def get(page):
        page.html = requests.get(page.url.string, headers=Scraper.HEADERS).text
        print(f"Scraping page {page.url.page_number}")
    
    @staticmethod
    def scrape(page_load: np.array):
        get = np.vectorize(Scraper.get)
        get(page_load)
        return page_load
```

page_load is an np.array of pages that need to be scraped. This is the initial state of a Page object...

```py
class Page:

    def __init__(self, url_detail):
        self.html = None
        self.url = Url(url_detail)
        self.houses = None
```

The url detail is passed directly to a Url object...

```py
class Url:

    def __init__(self, url_detail):
        self.domain = url_detail[3]
        self.state = url_detail[2]
        self.zip_code = url_detail[0]
        self.page_number = url_detail[-1]
        self.string = self.__str__()

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f"{self.domain}{self.state}/{self.zip_code}?page={self.page_number}"
```

The Url class breaks apart the url_detail record returned from the database so that it can be reconstructed easily into a scrape-able url. This is done via the `__str__()` method.

The scrape and build_page_load methods are called by the Manager via the work() method. The Managers job is to make the 'workers' (Scraper, DatabaseOperator and Locator) perform their tasks. The Manager class, and work() method look like this.

```py
class Manager:
    @staticmethod
    def work():
        url_details = DatabaseOperator.get_url_detail()
        page_load = Scraper.build_page_load(url_details)
        page_load = Scraper.scrape(page_load)
        raw_data = Locator.extract_houses(page_load)
        DatabaseOperator.inject(raw_data)
```

Once all pages have been constructed, I pass the page_load to the scrape method above, and run the get method on every page in that array. I need to scrape exactly 4 pages, and even though my program initializes exactly 4 Page objects, and constructs the url's properly, the first page gets requested twice, but every other page scrapes as intended. I have looked at similar posts and implemented time.sleep(5) to no avail.

Any suggestions as to what may be causing this? Let me know if any part of my question is unclear. Thanks!

Comment: So what calls the `scrape()` and `build_page_load()` methods?

Comment: will edit above post

Comment: Are you getting redirected from HTTP to HTTPS, and making two requests because of that?

Comment: @NickODell No I'm not...

Comment: @YoBoyAndy Can you add URL examples and imports?

Comment: I was able to reproduce your symptoms, but the duplicate I have indicated, suggested using `frompyfunc()`. I changed your vectorize line to: `get = np.frompyfunc(Scraper.get, 1, 1)` to get it to work.

Comment: @quamrana Thank you for this! You were able to help me solve 2 issues with this solution. The way that I inject the scraped data into the database was implemented with np.vectorize() as well. As a result, it was giving me a similar issue.

Comment: Its in the documentation. `np.vectorize()` can call the first item once to get the return type. After that it makes all the calls, including the first one again.